# Importing a module from a python file calling other modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, importerror

I am trying to run a specific code, now it requires the following importing of the Python file and I am getting an error, I have constructed a toy example to illustrate the problem. I am running on Python version 3.6.3. 
Consider the following folder structure.

```
root
  |- outside.py
  |- folA
       |- __init__.py
       |- inside.py
       |- folB
            |- __init__.py
            |- eveninside.py
```

Now the contents of these files are as follows.

***outside.py***

```
import folA.inside
print("Outside")
```

***inside.py***

```
import folB.eveninside
print("Inside")
```

***eveninside.py***

```
print("Even Inside")   #All inits are empty
```

Now when I run **inside.py** things run perfectly well and have expected outputs.
But when I run outside.py there is an error saying "no module named folB". I have tried appending the system path but there are no changes. Please explain me how to resolve this.

Answer (score -1):

This just come from the fact python goes look module from python path. Here when you launch outside he try to see if there is a folB in your directory where is outside.py.

Two solutions.

1. You use `sys.path.append` in inside.py to add the directory where is folA as a place to look for when trying to import module. I don't know how good practice it is.
2. In your case you can just write in inside.py `import folA.folB.eveninside. But obviously it won't work when you launch inside.py. In this case you have the first solution.

Comment: the second method of import folA.folB.eveninside works but the first solution does not work, the import error still happens.